# Java Service Layer Method - Primary Key or Hibernate Entity Arguments? Which is more idiomatic if using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, domain-driven-design

If using Java (Spring Boot), imagine there is one method in the service: **updateCompanyName**

Which is the more idiomatic method signature in the SERVICE LAYER of Spring Boot app:

......

updateCompanyName(Company company, String newName);

-or-

updateCompanyName(Long companyID, String newName);

......

In other words, should the controller hydrate the object from a DAO and pass a hibernate entity into a service layer, or should the service layer expect the primary key and hydrate the entity from hibernate?

Comment: First and foremost you should use the ubiquitous language and avoid technical terms such as update/select/delete/insert. i'm 100% certain that the domain experts in your (or your customers) companies never say "the company name has been updated", they most-likely always use the term "changed" as in "the company name was changed" (or renamed). "update" is only used in crud-like services that do not follow ddd

Comment: Thanks, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in a Layered architecture, the Controller (from the Presentation layer) extracts the data (i.e. companyID) from the input (i.e. request body) and calls an Application service by passing this data.

The Application service loads the Aggregate from the Repository, calls the *appropriate* method on it and then persists the Aggregate back to the Repository. This Application service show be thin, with no Business logic (which belongs in the Aggregate).

So, in your case, the answer is: the Controller calls `updateCompanyName(Long companyID, String newName);` on the Application service.

Comment: But then, don't you lose type safety?

Why not updateCompanyName(Company company, String newName)

Comment: @S.Shao you don't loose type safety if you use a dedicated type for company's ID, i.e. `class CompanyID`

Comment: @S.Shao you should not load the Aggregate inside controller because that's the Application's layer job.

Comment: thanks... are you saying to create a class called "CompanyID" just to support the primary key of another class "Company"?

Comment: @S.Shao I'm saying that you should make the implicit explicit. Having dedicated types for Aggregate IDs is a best practice in DDD

Comment: hi sir, what you suggest makes sense. Can you provide any good reference or suggestion regarding how to implement this in an application? Should CompanyID (the primary key reference to the entity) and Company (the entity) classes extend some base class that makes this type of coding easier in a large app with several domain entities? Thanks so much...